# getBase64ImageSrc to also get drawing on top of it

Tags: office-js

In Word, user needs to annotation (drawing) on an inline image or image in a picture content control.  How can I get the drawing and the image from web add-in?  I tried getBase64ImageSrc() but it seems to only get the image without the drawing on top of it.

Comment: How did you use `getBase64ImageSrc()` 'cause upon using it, I'm getting *"[ts] Cannot find name 'getBase64ImageSrc'."* ?